# Migration of Users very slow with d2d

Tags: users, migrations

I'm wondering what could be causing my migration to run so slowly.  I'm using dev versions of migrate and d2d as I always have without issue.  There are over 120,000 users and the first 2000-9000 import within a few seconds.

After that it only processes 2  at a time (about every 30 seconds).

d2d code:

```
  $common_arguments = array(
    'source_connection' => 'legacy',
    'source_version' => 6,
  );

  $arguments = $common_arguments + array(
    'description' => t('Migration of users from Drupal 6'),
    'machine_name' => 'User',
  );

  Migration::registerMigration('DrupalUser6Migration', $arguments['machine_name'], $arguments);
```

include file:

```
class User extends DrupalUser6Migration {
  public function __construct(array $arguemnts) {
    parent::__construct($arguemnts);

    $this->addFieldMapping('roles', 'roles')
      ->sourceMigration('Roles');
  }
}
```

The legacy database the data is coming from is on my local machine on the same SSD the new site is on.  Any ideas on why this is running so slow?  At the rate it's going out it will take over a month to import all of the users...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In settings.php set:

> $conf['password_count_log2'] = 1;

You will speed up how drupal handles user passwords: The problems reported here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2200181 ... seem to match yours, first 2000 in X seconds second 2000 in X.Y seconds etc...

Also, in php.ini set:

> max_execution_time to 0 (for unlimited) or a high number like 3000 rather than the default 30.

NB. Be sure to return the execution time to its default setting after the migration.

Comment: After doing this it is going slightly faster.  Instead of only doing 2 at a time it will process 2 at a time for about 5min, then process about 100, then go back to 2 at a time for another 5 or so minutes.

Comment: When I do as the guy in the article you linked did and limit to 1000 at a time, I still get 2 people importing every 30seconds

Comment: Ok do you have pathauto turned on? If yes turn it off..

Comment: No it is disabled.  I never had it enabled.

Comment: I've also disabled db log and a couple of other modules I was not using.  Now there are only standard core modules, views, migration, d2d, and a couple of features which create content types and taxonomy enabled.  It is still importing as ~1000 first run, then ~600 second, ~400 third, ~150 fourth, 2, 2, 2, 2, 100, 2, 2, 2

Comment: hmm... In your php.ini file what's  max_execution_time set to?

Comment: i checked my php info page and it says it's set to 30

Comment: ok bump that up to 3000 and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: They are importing MUCH faster now, though it does not give me output during migration, I am seeing the numbers climb about 1000/min when I run drush ms in terminal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15454/discussion-between-iain-maitland-and-cr47).

Answer (score 0):

CR47. I had same problem, I had to migrate 300 000 of users and batch migration became very slow. I used [drush migrate commands](https://www.drupal.org/node/1561820) and migration was rather fast (approximately 1000 of users per minute). 
I used

```
drush migrate-import User
```

where User is a machine name of my migration.

Also you can use

```
drush migrate-import User --feedback="1000 items"
```

In this case you will get feedback when 1000 of users will be migrated.